# How is a non-rotating black hole created

Tags: black-hole

1. How are non-rotating black holes formed?

I guess that non-rotating black holes are formed from non-rotating stars but I couldn't find any proof that such a star exists on the internet. If this is true can you also put up an example of such a star?

2. Does the matter absorption of a non-rotating black hole differ from a rotating black hole?

Comment: Also, one question per question please...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Sometimes it makes sense to ask two questions in the same post because they are quite related that they cannot live independently, IMO.

Comment: @Axl: Sometimes, when they are conjunct parts of the same question, but I don't see that this is really the case here? Granted, I'm no astrophysicist :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit My observation was not particularly referred to this post, but for a general case. I also think actually that these two questions should deserve their own separate post...

Comment: @Axl alright noted for the future, thanks guys!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All stars have *some* angular momentum. Conservation of angular momentum when the core of a star collapses means that it is very likely that most black holes are rapidly rotating, just as newly-born neutron stars are observed to be extremely fast-rotating.

Even if one were to have a star with a non-rotating core as it collapsed, the subsequent accretion of material with angular momentum would give the black hole that angular momentum.

Non-spinning black holes are a theoretical ideal that is unlikely to be found in nature.

The details of the accretion of material onto a black hole are complex and still the subject of theoretical and observational research. But yes, the details of accretion in spacetime governed by the [Kerr metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerr_metric) appropriate for rotating black holes will differ from those of a non-rotating [Schwarzschild](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_metric) black hole. Kerr black holes have an "ergosphere", outside their event horizons, where material is force to co-rotate with the black hole.

Comment: Sounds like an accretion disc inside ergosphere would act to spin up a non-rotating black hole.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger A non-rotating black hole doesn't have an ergosphere.

Comment: Now I *think*, of course not. Seems an accretion disk might still spin the thing up, even wo material necessarily crossing event horizon.

Answer (score 3):

For the first part of your question: A real black hole is formed from a collapsing start is likely to have angular momentum.  In theory a non-spinning black hole could be formed by collapse of a non-rotating star.  In theory, you could potentially also realize a non-rotating black hole if angular momentum were extracted from a rotating black hole via the Penrose process.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penrose_process

For the second part of your question, I think it's not quite clear what you mean.  The best that I can understand your question, I would say that matter is "absorbed" the same, although the path taken into the black hole may depend on its spin.

Comment: This begs the question, if we find a non-rotating black hole in the future, was it more likely created by natural processes or aliens extracting the energy via Penrose process? :)

Comment: I wonder if a kugelblitz would be non rotating.